# Linking python GUI to MySQL database

Tags: python, mysql-python

I'm a nube at the Python language and I'm having a hard time linking my Python GUI (in Tkinter) to a database. The layout is such that I want the end user to add Names to a database through an Entry widget. I tried to get the text to save to the database by using a variable, something like:

```
entr= Entry(frame1)
entr.grid(row=0, column=1)

var1=entr.get()

def save():
    """Save content in the entry box"""
    con = mdb.connect(host="localhost", user="root", passwd="xxxxxx", db="xxxxxxx")
    with con:
        cur=con.cursor()
        sql_update= "UPDATE Tests SET NAME='%s' WHERE id='%s'", (var1, id)
        cur.execute(sql_update)
        cur.close()
        con.commit()
        con.close()
```

this gives back the error message:

```
TypeError: query() argument 1 must be string or read-only buffer, not tuple
```

is there any way I can save data from the entry widget to the database without having to use `var1 = raw_input("Name: ")` somewhere else instead?

Thank you for your time! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace

```
    sql_update= "UPDATE Tests SET NAME='%s' WHERE id='%s'", (var1, id)
    cur.execute(sql_update)
```

with (preferred)

```
    sql_update= "UPDATE Tests SET NAME=%s WHERE id=%s"
    cur.execute(sql_update, (var1, id))
```

or

```
    sql_update= "UPDATE Tests SET NAME=%s WHERE id=%s", (var1, id)
    cur.execute(*sql_update)
```

---

If you wonder why your code did not work: Passing a tuple as a function argument will pass it as a single argument; while `,` creates tuples, it only does so if it's not inside a function declaration/call - in there it's the argument separator.

Using `*sql_update` unpacks the tuple into positional arguments so it works again. However, since you probably just use the variable to keep your code lines shorter, only put the SQL string in there and create the tuple inline when calling `cur.execute()`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I tried your methods and got no error this time, so I decided to test it:

Comment: I just noticed the quotes around `%s` - you need to remove them. The dbapi will take care of properly quoting your attributes (or pass them separately if supported by the database), so quoting them on your own will cause problems.

Comment: I tried your methods and got no error this time, so I decided to test it using cur.execute("SELECT * FROM Tests")
        rows=cur.fetchall()
        for row in rows:
            print row     The items added to the database look like this     (1L, "'")
(2L, "'")
(3L, "'")
(4L, "'")
(5L, "'") which means it's the variable that has the problem. I know it should be painfully obvious but is it the way that I'm referencing var1=ent.get() that gives this output? Any other way to get the text from the entry widget? Your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: See my comment from a minute ago; that probably broke your queries.

Comment: Any reference sites to the  learn linking python GUI  with MySQL query?